# Metodo por defecto de una clase al usar await/.then

Tags: javascript, nodejs, promesas

Puede que me esté dando algunas vueltas a la cabeza, pero para darles contexto, veo que hay funciones que mientras no es llamada como promesa, es un objeto tipico, pero al agregar async/await o ponerle .then/catch la misma se transforma en una promesa... Como ejemplo real, uso knex en node para generar las querys de mysql.

Caso base, tengo esto:

```javascript
client<User>("mitabla").select("[]").where('idUser', 1).first()
```

Si le hago un console.log, me da la informacion del objeto querybuilder, es decir, la función / código que hace la magia de knex.

Pero cuando hago esto

```javascript
client<User>("mitabla").select("[]").where('idUser', 1).first().then(console.log)
```

Me intenta realizar una consulta a la base de datos.

Quiero saber como es posible ésto, debido a que no encuentro la informacion indicada, intente leer su codigo en github pero no descifro este proceso. Quiero replicarlo con una clase, pero no se cual seria la funcion-prototipo que es llamada.

En mi codigo, quiero hacer algo como esto:

```javascript
function builder(name) {
    if (!(this instanceof arguments.callee)) {
        return new arguments.callee(name);
    }
    this.name = name;

    return this
}

builder.toString = () => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve(this.name)
        }, 500)
    });
}

builder("Diego").then(e => console.log(e)) // TypeError: builder(...).then is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente pude dar con la solucion buscando en stackoverflow... Es necesario extender le objeto promesa para tener esta funcionalidad.

```javascript
function builder(name) {
    if (!(this instanceof arguments.callee)) {
        return new arguments.callee(name);
    }

    this.name = name;
    this.promise = this.query()

    return this
};


// Extender Promesa
Object.setPrototypeOf(builder, Promise.prototype)
builder.prototype.catch = function(fail) { return this.promise.catch(fail) };
builder.prototype.then = function(success, fail) { return this.promise.then(success, fail) };

// Query
builder.prototype.query = function(){
    const state = this;
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        setTimeout(function(){
            resolve(state.name)
        }, 500)
    })
}


builder("foo").then(console.log).catch(console.log) // Launch a promise
console.log(builder("foo")) // function info
```